# Combining generics functions and generics in C#. Problem when casting to type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, automapper

I have been working with generics and getting an error when I try to cast a subclass to its generic parent. Currently my code fails at the cast to VenueRequestDTO. I have tried many things but cannot get this worked out.

```
    public interface VenueRequestCommand
    {
    }

    public class VenueRequestDTO<T, R, V> : DTO, VenueRequestCommand
    where T : VenueReservationDTO<V>
    where R : RequestorDTO 
    where V : VenueDTO
    {
        public List<T> Reservations { get; set; }
        public R Requestor { get; set; }
    }

    public class VenueRequestBaseDTO : VenueRequestDTO<VenueReservationBaseDTO, RequestorDTO, VenueBaseDTO> { }
    public class VenueRequestCreateUpdateDTO : VenueRequestDTO<VenueReservationCreateUpdateCommand, RequestorDTO, VenueCreateUpdateCommand> { }

    public T VenueRequestToDTO<T>(VenueRequest venueRequest) where T : VenueRequestCommand
    {
        var dto = MyConstants.Mapper.Map<T>(venueRequest);
        var venueRequestDTOGeneral = (VenueRequestCommand) dto;

        var venueRequestDTO =
            (VenueRequestDTO<VenueReservationDTO<VenueReservationVenueDTO<VenueBaseDTO>, VenueBaseDTO>, VenueReservationVenueDTO<VenueBaseDTO>, VenueBaseDTO, RequestorDTO>) venueRequestDTOGeneral;


        foreach (var item in venueRequestDTO.Reservations.Select(v => v.Venue))
            venueService.CalculateVenueCosts(item);

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(venueRequestDTO, typeof(T));
    }
```

I am able to use this function

```
public VenueRequestDTO<T, V, R> VenueRequestToDTO<T, V, R>(VenueRequest venueRequest)
    where T : VenueReservationDTO<V>
    where R : RequestorDTO 
    where V : VenueDTO
{   
    var settings = settingsService.GetVenuePortalSettings();
    var priceCategory = venueRequest.Requestor.PortalUser?.GetVenuePriceCategory();

    VenueRequestDTO<T,VRV,V, R> venueRequestDTO = MyConstants.Mapper.Map<VenueRequestDTO<T,VRV, V, R >>(venueRequest);

    foreach (var item in venueRequestDTO.Reservations.Select(v => v.Venue))
        venueService.CalculateVenueCosts(item);
        
    return venueRequestDTO;
}
```

But then I have to write out the types when using the method.
My goal is to be able to do something like this

```
VenueRequestToDTO<VenueRequestCreateUpdateDTO>(request);
```

Error is below. I removed one class to simplify the example above.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you intend this to work. In your first example `T` is a `VenueRequestCommand` not a `VenueRequestDTO<>`. So ofc you cannot cast it. Keep in mind that type inference is all or nothing, and it does not use the constraints when doing the inference.

Comment: I might add that my go to way for converting object hierarchies is the visitor pattern. Not sure if it would solve the particular problem you are having.

Comment: @mjwills I added the error to the post

Comment: @JonasH but the incoming type is always a derived class from VenueRequestBaseDTO. Can i rewrite the function so that i can somehow cast to this?

Comment: @Zapcrack, if `T` is always derived from `VenueRequestBaseDTO`, why not use that in your constraint?

Comment: Btw, `Convert.ChangeType` only works with objects that implement the `IConvertible` interface.

Comment: This looks like a classic case of using generics for scenarios where they don't really add type safety, since you end up converting all over the place anyway. Having to pass a `Type` to a method or using a base class as a type with appropriate virtual methods (or a cast in cases where it's really necessary) is often no less appropriate. AutoMapper is another thing that can really help to eliminate boring DTO boilerplate conversion.